# Renaming a set of file in separate folder in python

Tags: python, path

Hi guys have a problem with renaming a set of files in separate folder in python. i have a folder structure like

```
images/p_0/aaa.jpg,bbb.jpg
images/p_1/aaa.jpg,bbb.jpg
images/p_2/aaa.jpg,bbb.jpg
```

I need to rename these jpg to like

```
images/p_0/A-1.jpg,B-1.jpg
images/p_1/A-2.jpg,B-2.jpg
images/p_2/A-3.jpg,B-3.jpg
```

and i am using the `os.rename` method. I just don't get how to cycle through the folders and find the image and rename it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use os.walk and os.rename.

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(top, topdown=False):
    for name in files:
        #Rename your files and use os.path.join(root, name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [`os.listdir`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.listdir) or [`os.walk`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk), if you have a nested directory structure.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

# list all files
for filename in os.listdir('.'):
    print filename # do something with filename ...

def is_image(filename):
    """ Tiny filter function. """
    return filename.endswith(".jpg") or filename.endswith(".png")

# only consider files, which pass the `is_image` filter
for filename in filter(is_image, os.listdir('.')):
    print filename # do something with filename ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `os.listdir()` to get all the files in some directory.  You might also want to look through the rest of the [os module](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html) documentation.

Comment: Yes i tried that out it only lists the dir in the images folder i need to find the files inside the dirs and rename them

Comment: So have two loops:  `for dirname in os.listdir("images"): for filename in os.listdir("images/" + dirname"): do_something()`

Comment: Karmastan, you should use `os.path.join("images", dirname)` instead of direct string concatenation.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to os.walk(), glob.glob() might be useful.